# Catalog of limits

Tags: support, big-list, sandbox

**WARNING:** This post contains hundreds of mathematical formulas. Do not open it on devices, where rendering of MathJax is slow!

For **more comprehensive catalog see https://mathindex.wordpress.com** (it includes more limits, series, finite sums, and recurrences).

---

This is an attempt to organize questions about evaluation of common limits. Discussed at [Catalog of standard exercises](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16708/)

#### Trigonometric limits

- [with sine, at $0$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16718/)
- [with sine, at $\infty$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16719/)
- [with sine, at points $\ne 0,\infty$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16720/)
- [with cosine (no sine), at $0$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16721/)
- [with cosine (no sine), at $\ne 0$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16722/)

Comment: I'm scared... :-(

Comment: @AsafKaragila Main reason I went ahead with this is to see what problems will appear with such a list, and thus give more concrete input to discussion in the other thread. This is just an experiment... script time is cheap.

Comment: I don't like this! My laptop can't load more than 5 of them without freqqzin up!!! I cny even type properly.pleaseleae condense into eperate links(put all 100 in a nother linkP

Comment: @user142198 I was afraid of that... Not sure what a solution could be: moving the catalog to a site where formulas are rendered as images (would that even help?) or splitting the answers into much smaller chunks, so that they get paginated (only 30 answers are displayed at once).

Comment: If the sets were all contained in seperate links I would only need to render seta of 100 by choice, I think I m loadin 500 atm

Comment: As in have each o these answers redirect to a separate page with thelists(so yes smaller chunks), does spoiler code stop the rendering untilscrollover?

Comment: ybe these statistics arehelpful in knowing how many you want to put on the page: it takes 46sef to load first 44,84sec for 118total, 144sec for 269 otal. I have 1gb ram dual core 1.6ghz

Comment: The above numbers were amount of time elapsed since page refresh and the right was number of  lines of latex had rendered thus far. Sorry if that was unclear(this was written and pasted from notepad).

Comment: +6 for your effort...

Comment: I think it would be better if the posts about the same limit were grouped together (even if they are not exact duplicates, for example if they require some specific method, or avoiding some method). For example this limit is three times in one of your lists: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/finding-the-limit-of-1-cosx-x-as-x-to-0-with-squeeze-theorem, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420698/evaluating-lim-x-to0-frac1-cosxx and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552016/find-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-cos-x-1x These 3 occurrences are quite far from each other.

Comment: I suppose the ordering is by question id at the moment? It would not save that much rendering, but we could do this: $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}$ [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36299/finding-the-limit-of-1-cosx-x-as-x-to-0-with-squeeze-theorem), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420698/evaluating-lim-x-to0-frac1-cosxx), [3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552016/find-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-cos-x-1x)

Comment: @MartinSleziak The order is by ad-hoc "hotness points", equal to 20*(total score of answers) plus the number of views. When the same limit appears multiple times, the first appearance should be the canonical one. Rearranging them by hand isn't in my plans; the idea was to make content better accessible with an automatic tool.

Comment: BTW some links (probably generated by some automated process) see to be incorrect. For example, one of the answers contains a link like this: [$\displaystyle \lim\frac{\sin x}{x}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/914072). It links to question about $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\left(x-x^2\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$ (BTW maybe we could move the discussion [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/jury-duty), so that we do not put too many comments here.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak The problem is with that question: the limit that the user is asking about is not found in the question, it's only in  the post title.  I'll edit.

Comment: As I asked also [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17458302#17458302), my main question is whether it is ok if other users edit the lists you generated; or whether we should keep them as they are. (I suppose I would not cause too much harm - you can always rollback the edits.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak They are marked community-wiki. Feel free to edit, though you might find the process pretty slow. After seeing how these look and perform, I don't think I'll keep adding to this thread. Putting also logarithmic limits, exponential, square roots, rational functions... would make browsing next to impossible. I'll try to come up with a better system outside of SE. This thing can sit here as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I have edited two limits (removing incorrectly detected questions, putting questions about the limits together). My edits are summarized here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17458855#17458855

Comment: To add to @user142198: currently it takes one full core of my quad-core 3.1Ghz Xeon with 8gb ram around 15 seconds to render this page. I should make a note to never open this page on my laptop. // Perhaps with an automatic tool it is possible to have it on a third-party site where the results can be better paginated to about 50 or 100 entries per page?

Comment: If some users plan to edit the answers to this post (as an experiment, whether we are able to make something reasonable out of them), maybe we should ask SE team to change the owner of the post to the Community User - this was done for [some other sandbox-type posts](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers#comment22087_4666).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Don't worry about that. If I get tired of pings, I'll ask for disassociation, but so far this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 6):

### Trigonometric limits: with sine, at $0$

1. $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/285313), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/184593), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312285), [5](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/93671), [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98920), [7](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/628252), [8](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/312458).
2. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} (1+ \sin 2x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102247)
3. [$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(\sin^2x)(e^y-1)}{x^2+3y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316806)
4. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r^3 \cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{r^2(r^2\cos^4\theta + \sin^2\theta)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/753381)
5. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{1/\sin(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/222255)
6. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x+\sin (\frac 1 x)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/379445)
7. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \ln[(1-\sin^2(x))^\frac{1}{2x}]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51707)
8. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)\cos(4x)}{x+x\cos(5x)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550279)
9. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{x - \sin(x)}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134051)
10. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\frac{\sin^2{x}}{x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^2{x}} - 1}{2x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14582)
11. [$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y} = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291538)
12. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(1-x)-\sin x}{1-\cos^2 x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167885)
13. [$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\sin^2x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/400541)
14. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}+\sin\sqrt{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528661)
15. $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}}=\frac{1}{6}$ [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217081), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/808324)
16. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(\cos(2x))}{x\sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/275308)
17. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(1/x)}{\sin(1/x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/816980)
18. [$\displaystyle \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sin (\sin x)}}{x}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55588)
19. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x\sin(\sin x) - \sin^{2}x}{x^{6}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437926)
20. [$\displaystyle \lim _{x\rightarrow 0}{\frac {\cos \left( x \right) \sin \left( x
     \right) -x}{ \left( \sin \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105593)
21. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{x-\sin x}{x-\tan x}=?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/508733)
22. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\tan x) - \tan(\sin x)}{\arcsin(\arctan x) - \arctan(\arcsin x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/80364)
23. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2{x^{2}}}{x^{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288601)
24. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0+} \left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^{1/{x^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632527)
25. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(2x)\sin(4x)}{x\sin(3x)}=\frac83$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/498013)
26. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(\frac{1}{x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/464998)
27. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\tan (\sin (x))-\sin (\tan (x))}{x^7} \right).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/741446)
28. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{6x}}{\sin{2x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143489)
29. [$\displaystyle  \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\Bigg( \frac {(\cos(x))^{\sin(x)} - \sqrt{1 - x^3}}{x^6}\bigg) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/799379)
30. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{\sin2x}-e^{\sin x}}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/827287)
31. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\ \frac{\dfrac{\sin x}{x} - \cos x}{2x \left(\dfrac{e^{2x} - 1}{2x} - 1 \right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157100)
32. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}  \left\lfloor\frac{x^2}{\sin x \tan x}\right\rfloor$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442831)
33. [$\displaystyle \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {0^ + }} {\left( {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}} \right)^{\frac{1}{x}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/635195)
34. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/394687)
35. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{5x} = \frac{\sin(0)}{0} = \frac{0}{0}
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/60619)
36. [$\displaystyle \lim _{x \to 0} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \ne 0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214010)
37. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{1-\cos^3 x}{x\sin2x}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/888081)
38. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\sin{(\tan{x})}-\tan{(\sin{x})}}{x^7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548832)
39. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin{3x}}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/143473)
40. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-\sin x}{\sin^3x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/241693)
41. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x^2}{ \ln ( \cos x^2 \cos x + \sin x^2 \sin x)} = -2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/153918)
42. [$\displaystyle \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac {\sin^2\theta}{\theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165404)
43. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos 3x-\cos x}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2\sin\frac{1}{2}(3x+x)\sin\frac{1}{2}(3x-x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2\sin2x\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2(2\sin x\cos x)\sin x}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-4\sin^2 x\cos x}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201470)
44. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\ \dfrac{\sin(\cos(x))}{\sec(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6848)
45. [$\displaystyle 
    \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin x} - \frac{1}{\tan x}\right)
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/764365)
46. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{r \to 0} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{r^2}}}{r^4\cos^4 \theta+r^4 \sin^4 \theta } $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107171)
47. [$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\to 0}  \frac {\tan(2x)}{\sin(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467780)
48. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^2}{\sin^2 x}=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146147)
49. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin 2x}{ x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528456)
50. [$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/215438)
51. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{ x\to 0 } \frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^3}? $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351038)
52. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\tan(3x^2) + \sin^2(5x)}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32521)
53. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sin(2x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851789)
54. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \Bigl(\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\Bigr)^{1/x^{3}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61582)
55. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x + \tan x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/612241)
56. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/364552)
57. [$\displaystyle  \lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sinh x}{x} =1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/851856)
58. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin5x}{\sin4x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/882392)
59. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{x \tan x^2}{\cos 5x \sin^3 3x}\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318287)
60. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475073)
61. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0^{+}}\dfrac{\tan{(\tan{x})}-\tan{(\sin{x})}}{\tan{x}-\sin{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/490470)
62. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cos x + \cos 2x + \dots+ \cos nx - n}{\sin x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610729)
63. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x - \sin x}{x^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279967)
64. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \large \large \frac{\sin \sqrt {(x+h)^2+1}-\sin \sqrt {x^2+1}}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450717)
65. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sin(x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565520)
66. [$\displaystyle  \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}^{\frac{1}{1-\cos x}} = 
    \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\exp\left( \frac{\ln(\frac{\sin x}{x})}{1-\cos x} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891242)
67. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{\dfrac{1}{1 - \cos x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/206536)
68. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left (\frac 1x- \frac 1{\sin x} \right )
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/422351)
69. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3}} - \frac1{\sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/878760)
70. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{{6}/{x^{2}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/447312)
71. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1+x\sin(2x)-\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/411850)
72. [$\displaystyle \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{
    \sin x}{x}\right)^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/605202)
73. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}{\dfrac{e^x-\sin x-1}{x^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/285942)
74. [$\displaystyle  \lim \limits_{x\to0} (\sin x)^x $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73102)
75. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-x}{\sin3x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/502855)
76. [$\displaystyle \lim_{\theta \to 0^+}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta^2}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776463)
77. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{z \to 0} |z \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{z})|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/281518)
78. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin (6x)}{\sin(2x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565286)
79. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(1-\cos(x))}{x^2e^x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/821350)
80. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \cos \bigg(\pi x^2 \csc (\frac {x} {2}) \cot (6x) \bigg)=\lim_{x\to 0} \cos \bigg(\pi x^2 (\frac {\cos (6x)} {\sin (\frac {x} {2}) \sin 6x}  \bigg)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/203260)
81. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt{5x+3}-\sqrt 3}{5^{\sin(7x)}-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255890)
82. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\tan(\tan x) - \sin(\sin x)}{\tan x -\sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/516483)
83. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\sin(x)\ln{\sin{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786501)
84. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^2+\frac{1}{x})-\sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423938)
85. [$\displaystyle \lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos\theta·\sin(r^2)}{r}=\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos\theta·r^2}{r}=\lim_{r\rightarrow0}{\cos\theta·r}=0 \text{ for all }\theta \in [0,2\pi)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276643)

Answer (score 5):

### Trigonometric limits: with sine, at points $\ne 0,\infty$

1. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to a}\sin x=\sin a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136999)
2. [$\displaystyle \lim x\sin (1/x) = \lim\, x \dfrac{\sin (1/x)}{x(1/x)} = \lim\, x/x = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515357)
3. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi} \frac{\sin5x}{\sin3x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/244158)
4. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{(x^2-1)\sin(3x-3)}{\cos(x^3-1)\tan^2(x^2-x)}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214076)
5. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi/2}   \frac{\sin(x)}{x}    = \lim_{x\to\pi/2}  \frac{\cos(x)}{1}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87380)
6. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi/2}(\tan x)(\ln \sin x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358722)
7. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos(x)-\sin(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{2\cos^{2}(x)-1}{\cos(x)-\sqrt{1-\cos^{2}(x)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/275215)
8. [$\displaystyle \lim \limits _{x \rightarrow 1} \dfrac{\sin (\pi x^{\alpha})}{\sin (\pi x^{\beta})}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/859079)
9. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to2^-}h(x)=\lim_{x\to2^-}\sin k(x)=\sin(2k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202279)
10. [$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (2,-2)} \dfrac{\sin(x+y)}{x+y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/283747)
11. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_ {x \to 1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{1 - x^2}
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261798)
12. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin^2x-1}{\sin x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/906892)
13. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{2\sin{(x)}-1}{\sqrt{3}\tan{(x)}-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/383912)
14. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{1-\tan x}{1-\sqrt{2}\sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/607586)
15. [$\displaystyle  \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1} \left( \dfrac{-ax + \sin(x-1) + a} { x + \sin(x-1) -1 } \right)^{\dfrac{1-x}{1-\sqrt x} } = \dfrac 1 4 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/818138)
16. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{1 - \sin{x}}{(2x - \pi)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507577)
17. [$\displaystyle \lim_{t\rightarrow1^+}\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\pi t)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398371)
18. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi/3}\frac{\sqrt{3+2\cos x}-2}{\ln(1+\sin3x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/377811)
19. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin(x^2-1)}{x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/415880)
20. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\ln(\tan x)}=\left(\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\ln(\tan x)}\right):\cos x = \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\tan x-1}{\frac{\ln(\tan x)}{\cos x}} = \frac{0}{\frac{0\cdot{2}}{0\cdot\sqrt{2}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/530806)
21. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to\pi}\left(\dfrac1{\sin(x)}\right)^{x-\pi}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/636165)
22. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin x - (\sin x)^{\sin x}}{1 - \sin x + ln(\sin x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610152)
23. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x\to\pi/6}\frac{1 - 2\sin{x}}{2\sqrt{3}\cos{x} - 3}
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/865509)
24. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi}\frac{e^{\sin x} - 1}{x - \pi}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/814507)
25. [$\displaystyle \lim \frac{\sin(h)}{h}=1,\ \mbox{as}\ h\to0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897740)
26. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pi}\sin(x + \sin x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/844134)
27. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi}\frac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(2x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/294496)
28. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\sin{(x^2-1)}}{x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/788048)
29. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to \sqrt{n}^+} \frac{n\sin^2(x\pi)-n\sin^2(\sqrt{n}\pi)}{x-\sqrt{n}} =
    n\pi\sin(2\pi\sqrt{n})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/272811)
30. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \tan^2(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} = \lim\limits_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{1 - \cos^2(x)}{1-\sin^2(x)} = \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/281647)
31. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos2(x-\pi)}{\sin2(x-\pi)}\frac{\cos(x-\frac\pi2)}{\sin(x-\frac\pi2)} = \lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{-\cos2x}{-\sin2x}\frac{-\sin x}{-\cos x} = \lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos2x}{2\sin x\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac12\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{\cos2x}{\cos x}\frac{1}{\cos x}=\frac12
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/260161)
32. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to {\pi/2}} \frac {\sin x -(\sin x)^{\sin x}} {1-\sin x+\log (\sin x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/409397)
33. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow -\pi}\large{\frac {\sin(4x)}{x^2+\pi x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/534707)
34. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \pi/4} \frac{1-\tan x }{1-\sqrt2 \, \sin x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723048)
35. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi/ 6} \frac{(2\sin x + \cos(6x))^2}{(6x - \pi)\sin(6x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/883756)
36. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{6}} (2+\cos {6x})^{\ln |\sin {6x}|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843590)
37. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \left((x - 1)\sin\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/232924)
38. [$\displaystyle \underset{x\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{2{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{3}}+{{x}^{2}}\sin x}{{{x}^{2}}-5{{x}^{4}}+{{x}^{3}}\sqrt{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83325)
39. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \left( \frac{\sin x}{\sin a} \right)^{\frac{1}{x-a}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/371698)
40. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a}[\cos(2 \pi x)-\sin(2 \pi x) \cot(\frac{\pi x}{a})]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/401097)
41. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to π/2} \frac{1-\sin x+\cos x}{\sin 2x -\cos x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739645)
42. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \pi} \dfrac{\sin(3x)}{\sin(5x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/570594)
43. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\sin (x-1)}{x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209412)
44. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\log y=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}[\tan x\log(1+\cos x)]=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\log(1+\cos x)}{\cos x} \times \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/703807)
45. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to ∞}e ^ {-\sin{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732727)
46. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi/4} \frac{\tan x-1}{\sin x-\cos x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/878914)
47. [$\displaystyle \lim _{ { x }\to { 0 } }{ \frac { \sin x-\arctan x }{  {x }^{ 2 }\log(1+x) } }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/439001)
48. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin x-(\sin x)^{\sin x}}{1-\sin x+\log_e \sin x}=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/328416)
49. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^{\tan x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/685828)
50. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \dfrac{x\sin\lbrace x\rbrace}{x-1} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/830209)
51. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \dfrac{\pi}{4}} \dfrac{\sin x-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{x-\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533123)
52. [$\displaystyle \lim_{E \to U} \frac{1}{4}\left[\frac {U^2}{E(E-U)}\right]\sin^2 k'L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/179447)
53. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,1)} \frac {\sin(x) - \sin (y)} {x-y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/913830)
54. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \sin{x} = ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895979)
55. [$\displaystyle \lim _{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}         \frac{[\frac{x}{2}]}{\log(\sin x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/490581)
56. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \frac{\pi }{4}}\frac{\sin2x-\cos^{2}2x-1}{\cos^{2}2x+2\cos^{2}x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548937)
57. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to h^+}c_1\cos(x-a)+c_2\sin (x-a)  $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/577824)
58. [$\displaystyle  \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1  y \to 1} (2y-x)^{\frac{1}{\sin(2y-x-1)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/660012)
59. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to1}{\dfrac{1-x}{1-\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi \cdot x}{2}\right)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817474)

Comment: Why did you make 49 Large?

Comment: @user1729 This whole catalog was automatically generated (modulo some later edits by Martin Sleziak). The reason 49 is large is that [it's large in the post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/685828/). If the font should be fixed, the higher priority is fixing it there rather than here. The thing we have here is experimental. \

Comment: Okay, that explains it. I've edited it in both places.

Answer (score 3):

### Trigonometric limits: with cosine (no sine), at $\ne 0$

#### At finite nonzero points

1. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \cos^{-1}(x)=\cos^{-1}(\lim_{x \rightarrow a} x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489995)
2. [$\displaystyle 
   \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{\cos(x)\ln(x-a)}{\ln(e^x-e^a)}
   $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/538846)
3. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos(x)}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}\;$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/415572)
4. [$\displaystyle 
   \lim_{x\rightarrow{\frac\pi2 }} (\sec(x) \tan(x))^{\cos(x)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/507967)
5. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to \pi/2} {\cos x\over x-\pi/2} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/247646)
6. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow (-1)^{+}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}-\sqrt{\cos^{-1}x}}{\sqrt{x+1}} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337603)
7. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow α}\frac{1 - \cos(ax^2+bx+c)}{(x-α)^2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/334606)
8. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\pi/4}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288574)
9. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \pi/2} \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2\cos x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209978)
10. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 3} (x^2-2x-3)^2\cos\left(\pi \over x-3\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519224)
11. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\,\to\tfrac{\pi}{6}} \frac{\cos(2x) - \frac{1}{2}}{x - \frac{\pi}{6}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264688)
12. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow o}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/633039)
13. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \cos(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/489917)
14. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} (1+\cos x)^{\tan x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/703807)
15. [$\displaystyle \lim \sup \cos(n\pi/12)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319072)
16. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to1}\left(\frac{1+\cos(\pi x)}{\tan^2(\pi x)}\right)^{\!x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/524860)
17. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1} (1-x)^{\cos[(\Pi/2) x)]}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420674)
18. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to -2} \left(x-21-12\sqrt[3]{x-6}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\cos(x+2)}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/877913)
19. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} \cos{x} = ?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/895979)
20. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{\cos(x-2)-1}{x^{2}+x-6}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/853808)
21. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\pi}\dfrac{1+\cos^3x}{1-\cos^2x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/800982)
22. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to1}{\dfrac{2}{\pi \cdot \cos\left(\dfrac{\pi \cdot x}{2}\right)}} = \frac{2}{0} = \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817474)

#### At infinity

1. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty }\cos (\pi\sqrt{n^{2}-n}).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45759)
2. [$\displaystyle \lim_{\nu\to\infty} \left[ \nu^\mu P_\nu^{-\mu}\left(\cos \frac{x}{\nu} \right) \right]= J_\mu(x) \qquad(1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/129131)
3. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}{\frac{\cos(\frac{1}{x})-1}{\cos(\frac{2}{x})-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/481421)
4. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left( \cos{\frac{\pi}{n}} + \cos{\frac{2\pi}{n}} + \ldots +\cos{\frac{n\pi}{n}} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12107)
5. [$\displaystyle 
   \lim \limits_{n \to \infty}
   \left[\cos\left(x \over 2\right)\cos\left(x \over 4\right)
         \cos\left(x \over 8\right)\ \cdots\ \cos\left(x \over 2^{n}\right)\right]
   $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455995)
6. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty } \left(\frac{n^3}{4n-7}\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac1n\right)-1\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146661)
7. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty}(e^{-x}+2\cos3x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299094)
8. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty } \, n
      \left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty } \, n \left(\left(1-\cos \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)^z \left(1-\cos
      \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\right)^{-z}-1\right) = 2z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16059)
9. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {\cos 1 \cdot \arccos \frac{1}{n}+\cos\frac
   {1}{2} \cdot \arccos \frac{1}{(n-1)}+ \cdots +\cos \frac{1}{n} \cdot
    \arccos{1}}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/149734)
10. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left ( \cos1+\cos(\frac{1}{2})+\cos(\frac{1}{3}) +...+\cos (\frac{1}{n}) \right )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288802)
11. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \cos^x(c)=0.7390851332$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227317)
12. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{n\to\infty} n\sqrt{2-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}=2\pi
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/760272)
13. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \, \cos \left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^{x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776201)
14. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}n})=s$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/484613)
15. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218722)
16. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n^2\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\sqrt{1-\cos(1/n)+\ldots}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/453139)
17. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty } \,\cos (1) \cos \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \cos \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\cdots \cos \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/628344)
18. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}{n \cos(\pi/2 + 1/n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/210237)
19. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\underset{n}{\underbrace{\cos(\cos(...\cos x))}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/288958)
20. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\tan{n}}{1.5^n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2{n}}}{1.5^n\cdot\ln1.5} =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\ln1.5\cdot\cos^2n\cdot1.5^n} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/544729)
21. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(1)\cos(0.5)\cos(0.25)\ldots \cos(1/2^n)
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/618739)
22. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(x+\cos x)}{x}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/490051)
23. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left(\cos\frac xm\right)^{m}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/284881)
24. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|\cos{1}|+|\cos{2}|+|\cos{3}|+\cdots+|\cos{n}|}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/650403)
25. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos \dfrac {\pi}{2^2}\cos \dfrac {\pi}{2^3}\cos \dfrac {\pi}{2^4}......\cos \dfrac {\pi}{2^n}=\dfrac {2}{\pi}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349793)
26. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}x \cos (1/x) = \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729195)
27. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\frac{\cos\pi n}{n^2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/853030)
28. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} x\cos\frac{1}{x}=\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/897335)
29. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[n \; \arccos
    \left( \left(\frac{n^2-1}{n^2+1}\right)^{\cos \frac{1}{n}} \right)\right]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/663757)
30. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}x \cos x \neq \infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/729402)
31. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{n^n+n^{n+1}+\cdots+n^{2n}} \cdot\left(1-\cos{\frac{3}{n}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643084)
32. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}x^{2}\ln\left(\cos\left(\pi \over x\right)\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/590115)
33. [$\displaystyle \lim_{t\to\infty} (\cosh x)^{1/x}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776466)
34. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (\cos x)^\frac{1}{x^2} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/693579)
35. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3+\cos x+e^{-2x}}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/697402)
36. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)-1\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/784882)
37. [$\displaystyle \lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\left(\cos ^2\left(x^3\right)+x\right)}{x!}\right)\:$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/821174)
38. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{n\to\infty}  ∫_{-1}^1f (t)\cos^2(nt)\,\mathrm dt$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276249)
39. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \cos{kx} P_{\frac{1}{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/414277)
40. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{4(n-1)} \right) \right|^{2n-1} = L$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/670424)
41. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(a_n) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/578441)
42. [$\displaystyle \lim_{\theta\rightarrow -\infty}\dfrac{\cos\theta}{3\theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/308153)

Answer (score 2):

### Trigonometric limits: with sine, at $\infty$

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{\sin 1+2\sin \frac{1}{2}+\cdots+n\sin \frac{1}{n}}{n}$ [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/390115), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231256)
2. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} x \sin x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/131861)
3. [$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} |\sin(\pi \sqrt{n^2+n+1})|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349522)
4. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{ x \to \infty  }{ \frac { x+\sin { x }  }{ x }  } =1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/362940)
5. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}\sin_{n}(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/276135)
6. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}{\sin{\sqrt{x+1}}-\sin{\sqrt{x}}}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/394899)
7. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\frac{1}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/208694)
8. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty }\sqrt[n]{ \frac{\left | \sin1 \right |}{1}\cdot\frac{\left | \sin2 \right |}{2}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{\left | \sin n \right |}{n}} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/231226)
9. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225374)
10. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\big(\max \{\sin 1, \sin 2, \ldots ,\sin n\}\big) = 1?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341378)
11. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(x^2+4)}{\sinh^{-1}x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152344)
12. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/475506)
13. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} 2^x \sin\left(\frac \pi {2^x}\right)=\pi.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/525744)
14. [$\displaystyle \left|\left(\frac{1+\sin(k)}{2}\right)^k-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+\sin(n)}{2}\right)^n\right|<\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/828563)
15. [$\displaystyle \mathop{\lim}\limits_{x \to \infty}\left({x\space\sin^{2} x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66222)
16. [$\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sin \frac {1} {3^{n}z}\rightarrow 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123754)
17. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (x/(x+1))(\sin(x^2)) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x \sin x^2 }{x+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/226314)
18. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\sin\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\right)^{n\cos\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\left(1+\sin\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\right)^\frac {1}{\sin\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)} \right)^{n\cdot\cos\left(\frac {1}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/436122)
19. [$\displaystyle  \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{(x + 10\sin x )}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/189060)
20. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\tan(\pi/n)}{n\sin^2(2/n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/200985)
21. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} (\sin {\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}}+\sin {\frac{n}{n^2+2^2}}+\cdots+\sin {\frac{n}{n^2+n^2}})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/310649)
22. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sin(n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/526857)
23. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\sin{(n^m)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/509678)
24. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{{\sin\frac{2}{2n}+\sin\frac{4}{2n}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+\sin\frac{2n}{2n}}}{{\sin\frac{1}{2n}+\sin\frac{3}{2n}+\cdot \cdot \cdot+\sin\frac{2n-1}{2n}}}\right)^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151216)
25. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin(nt)}{\sin(t)}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172286)
26. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{3^{-n}\sin(3^{(1-n)})}{\tan(3^{1-2n})} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/335634)
27. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{n}(-\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218722)
28. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}(\sin x+2)\ln(-x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/153044)
29. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[x]{1+\sin(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374543)
30. [$\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {1+\cos \dfrac {x} {n}+\cos \dfrac {2x} {n}+\ldots +\cos\dfrac {\left( n-1\right) x} {n}} {n } = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/127351)
31. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\bigl(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1}\bigr)=0 
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732611)
32. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac {7 \sin x}{\sqrt{5x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/487785)
33. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\left(\sin(2\pi en!)-\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/339315)
34. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/857532)
35. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin n}{n}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/221251)
36. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} 5^x \sin\left(\frac{a}{5^x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/251311)
37. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x-\sin x}{x+\cos x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1-\cos x}{1-\sin x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/656266)
38. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{4n + \sin \sqrt{n} + \cos (\tfrac{1}{n^2}) + 17}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287358)
39. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x(1+ \sin(x))}{x-\sqrt{1+x^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/544909)
40. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-\frac{1}{2}\sin x}{x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/601115)
41. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \dfrac{x + 5 \sin x}{x-\cos x} = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455115)
42. [$\displaystyle \lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}\pi \cos \left( \frac{2\pi}{3n}\right) \sin \left( \frac{4\pi}{3n}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176689)
43. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin (x)+\cos (3x)}{x+2}\;\;?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/473888)
44. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sin\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\right)=\sin(0)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404211)
45. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sin((2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}) \sin(2n\pi + \frac{1}{2n\pi}))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/606559)
46. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2\left( \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}\right)}{1-\cos^2\frac{1}{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/515164)
47. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac{\sin\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/590082)
48. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to \pm \infty}\left(\cos\left(e^{x^{1/3}+\sin x}\right)\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/531300)
49. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\sin \frac {c}{x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/790302)
50. [$\displaystyle \lim_{ x\to \infty}\cos x^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/645557)
51. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n\sin(2\pi e n!)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/640110)
52. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4n^3 + 1)(4n - 2)!n\sin{\frac{2}{n}}}{(4n + 1)!+3} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/238278)
53. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac {\cos^5x\sin^5x} {x^8\sin^2x-2x^7\sin x\cos^2x+x^6\cos^4x+x^2\cos^8x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/337081)
54. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}(n+2)^{2}\sin\frac{1}{n}=\infty.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/592100)
55. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^n\sin(\frac{n}{\pi})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/560234)
56. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{5 n^2 +\sin n}{3 (n+2)^2 \cos(\frac{n \pi}{5})},$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/83919)
57. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x-\sin x }{x-\tan x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/818346)
58. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sin\frac1x+\cos\frac1x\right)^x=e.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/330065)
59. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty}{x^{\frac{5}{3}}\cdot\left[{\left(x+\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}^{\frac{1}{3}} -x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/480463)
60. [$\displaystyle \mathop{\lim}\limits_{x \to \infty}x\left(\frac{1}{x}\sin x-1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=(0k-1+0)\cdot\mathop{\lim}\limits_{x \to \infty}x,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/65908)
61. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sin n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677719)
62. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\;\sin(x)?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/360608)
63. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{|\sin1|}1+\cdots+\frac{|\sin n|}{n}\ }\,.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/597013)
64. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|\sin n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/906132)
65. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{\sin(\pi/n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532303)
66. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x - \sin(x) \log(1+x)}{x^7}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/834641)
67. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty } \left |\sin n  \right |n=\infty $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309680)
68. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln (1+n^{3})-\ln(n^{6})}{\sin ^{3}(n)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/229646)
69. [$\displaystyle \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {1} {n}\left( \dfrac {\sin \dfrac {x} {2}\cos \dfrac {x} {2}\left(\dfrac {1} {n}-1\right)} {\sin \dfrac {x} {2n}}\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/128510)
70. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \sin{1\over n}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/568894)
71. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \limsup_{n\to \infty} \sin(n) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/359154)
72. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\left(n\sin{(2e\pi\cdot n!)}-2\pi\right)=\dfrac{2\pi(2\pi^2-3)}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492179)
73. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}(\sin\frac{\ln2}{2}+\sin\frac{\ln3}{3}+\ldots+\sin\frac{\ln n}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580398)
74. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \sin(2 \pi e n!)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/561313)
75. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n \sin\left(\frac{1}{X_n}\right)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/427598)
76. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\sin(5x)}{\sin(x)\sin(2x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/500151)
77. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sin(n)-n)=-\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/350864)
78. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{\ 1+|\sin n|}{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/516331)
79. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\sin (1/x) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872275)
80. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\cot{\frac{2}{n}}+n\csc{\frac{3}{n^3}}}{\csc{\frac{3}{n}} + n\cot{\frac{2}{n^2}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\frac{2}{n}}{\tan{\frac{2}{n}}}\cdot\frac{1}{2n^2}+\frac{\frac{3}{n^2}}{\sin{\frac{3}{n^2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{\frac{3}{n}}{\sin{\frac{3}{n}}}\cdot \frac{1}{3n^2}+\frac{\frac{2}{n^2}}{\tan{\frac{2}{n^2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=...=\frac{2}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133814)
81. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x^3 \left(\tan{\frac{1}{x}}\right)\left(\sin{\frac{3}{x^2}}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103493)
82. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{\sin{\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}}}} = \sqrt{\sin{3 \sqrt{ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} }}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111653)
83. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} x\sin({1\over x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/782971)
84. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{6n^3+2n^2-7}{(n+\sin(n^2))(n^2+1)} =6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/199779)
85. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sin\frac{2\pi}{3^{n}} \sim \frac{2\pi}{3^{n}}\tag{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397605)
86. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{4x^3 - 2x + 1}{8x^3 + \sin(x^2) - x^{-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/451924)
87. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sin(x))^n $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/271389)
88. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} {\sin(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565469)
89. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty}2^n\sin(2^{-n}) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/684995)
90. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}n\sin\left(\frac1n\right)=1?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/816066)
91. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{3 - \sin(e^x)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705774)
92. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^n+2n^n+n!}{(n+1)^4+\sin n+(3n)!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/558092)
93. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\sin n\right|^\frac1n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/465421)
94. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \sin (2\pi e n!).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/374137)
95. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty+}\frac{\frac{\cos(n!)}{n!+2n}-\sin\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)(n^8+\ln n)^{\frac14}}{(n^3+n^2)^{\frac13}-n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/307952)
96. [$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\underbrace{\sin{\sin{\cdots\sin{x}}}}_{n},x\in R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/736725)
97. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} x^2 \sin\dfrac{1}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/846559)
98. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin[xf(x)]}{x\cdot\sin[f(x)]}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565258)
99. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x+\sin(x)}{x+1}=1.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/784094)

Answer (score 1):

### Trigonometric limits: with cosine (no sine), at $0$

1. $\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x} $ [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36299), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81768), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420698), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/552016)
2. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln[\cos(x)]}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51707)
3. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}}{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\cos\sqrt{x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528661)
4. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos (1- \cos x)}{x^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/118871)
5. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos(x)}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/415570)
6. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln (\cos ax)}{\ln (\cos bx)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/171031)
7. $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} {1-\cos x\over x^2} = \frac12$ [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/204125), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/202308), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/818000)
8. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \cos(\frac{1}{x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/464998)
9. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{1-\cos x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/513721)
10. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1- \cos 5x}{x^2} = \frac{25}{2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/567263)
11. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287644)
12. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos 3x-\cos x}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/201470)
13. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{\cosh x\cosh 2x\cosh 3x \cdots \cosh nx-1}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/191845)
14. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log\cos x}{\log\cos 3x}
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163568)
15. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\ln (\cos x)}{x\sqrt {1 + x}  - x} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/651342)
16. [$\displaystyle \lim_{(a,b)\to (0,0)} \frac{\cos^{-1}(f(a,b,\lambda,\gamma))}{\cos^{-1}(f(a,b,1,\gamma))}=|\lambda|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81136)
17. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} (\frac{\cos x } {x e^{x}}- \frac{1}{x})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/637845)
18. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \cos \bigg(\pi x^2 \csc (\frac {x} {2}) \cot (6x) \bigg)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/203260)
19. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y) = \dfrac{\cos(x) -1 - {x^2 \over 2}}{x^4 + y^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404692)
20. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left[ \frac{\ln(\cos x)}{x\sqrt{1+x}-x} \right]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/842546)
21. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^3}{\tan^3(2x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{6\cos^3(2x)}{48\cos^3(2x)} = \frac{6}{48} = 0.125$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157301)
22. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\arcsin x - \arctan x}{e^x-\cos x -x^2 -x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/643787)
23. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x(1- \cos x)}{3x^2}
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499434)
24. [$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\cos {(xy)} - 1}{x^2y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195981)
25. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/159662)
26. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{(x,y)\to (4,0)}y^2\cos\left({1\over(x-4)^2+y^2}\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/445433)
27. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\frac{1-\cos(1-\cos x)}{x^4}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/234503)
28. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \, x^{1/3}\cos(1/x) = 0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85538)
29. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t^2}{1-\cos^2t}  $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/635665)
30. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1-3x)^\frac{1}{3} -(1-2x)^\frac{1}{2}}{1-\cos(\pi x)}.
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/570406)
31. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot \operatorname{cosec}(2x)}{\cos(5x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/614948)
32. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x \to  0}\frac{\left [ \cos(a+x)-\cos(a-x) \right ]^2}{\tan^2(3x)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/531503)
33. $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}2}{x^4+y^4}$ [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/418208), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/404692/)
34. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0 }\frac{e^{\arctan(x)}-e^{\arcsin(x)}}{1-\cos^3(x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632993)
35. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos(ax)}{ax}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87491)
36. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln(\cos x)}{\ln(\cos 3x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/774878)
37. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}h\cos\frac1h\stackrel{?}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349300)
38. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\tan \left(\pi\cos^{2}x\right)}{x^2} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/341434)
39. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt[m]{\cos x}-\sqrt[n]{\cos x}}{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/602597)
40. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\cos(\frac1x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/637887)
41. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{|\cos h-1|}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437526)
42. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt[3]{\cos{x}}}{1-\cos{\sqrt[3]{x}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739919)
43. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {\arccos(\cos^2h)} {h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576516)
44. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos3x-\cos x}{\tan2x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527664)
45. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/614320)
46. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2 - \cos(3x) - \cos(4x)}{x}?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/776500)
47. [$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 10} \frac{t^2 - 100}{t+1} \cos\left( \frac{1}{10-t} \right)+ 100$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398409)
48. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{2+p\cos{x}}{3-2\cos{x}} = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132790)
49. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{1-\cos(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/545995)
50. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{k \to 0}{f(k) = 2} \;+\; \lim_{k \to 0}{k^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos {\frac{1}{k^2}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/135614)
51. [$\displaystyle 
     \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{2x}-x^2+x}{\cos(x)-1} = ~?
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291549)
52. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{1-\cos x \cdot \sqrt{\cos2x} }{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/261698)
53. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{\left| \cos(\frac{\pi}{2+ \pi h}) \right| - \left|cos(\frac{\pi}{2})\right|}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/886563)
54. [$\displaystyle 
    \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}\cdot\left[\arccos\left(\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^{2}-
    2x\cdot \cos(y)+1}}-\frac{1}{x}\right)-y\right]
    $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/465973)
55. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}{ \left|{\cos h \over h}\right|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/437563)
56. [$\displaystyle \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2\cos \theta}{r^2+\cos\theta}=\frac{2\cos \theta}{\cos\theta}=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/671160)
57. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0} \frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{3}+h)-\frac{1}{2}}{h}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519096)
58. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \frac{2^x-\cos\left(x\right)}{3^x-\operatorname{ch}\left(x\right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/632976)
59. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt[3]{\cos x}}{x(1-\cos\sqrt{x})}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/767885)
60. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \cos x=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527094)
61. [$\displaystyle  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-\cos x \cos(2x)}{x^2} \, . $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214444)
62. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim _{x\to \:0}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\cos \left(2x\right)}}{\sqrt{2}x}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/855228)
63. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} {x^2 \over \cos (3x) - 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488478)
64. [$\displaystyle \lim_{h \to 0}\cos(a + h) = \cos(a)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/875145)
65. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \left(\csc(x^2)\cos(x)-\csc(x^2)\cos(3x) \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/432762)
66. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos(2x))}{\ln(\cos(3x))}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/883053)
67. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac {1-\cos x}{1-\sec^2x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/727805)
68. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1 - \cos{x}}{x}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817597)
69. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} |x|^\alpha\cos(1/x^2) = 0.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151846)
70. [$\displaystyle  \ \lim_{ x \to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{x} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/800035)
71. [$\displaystyle \lim_{r \rightarrow 0}  \frac{2r\cos(r^2)}{2r} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/844732)
72. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} x^2\cos\left(\frac1x\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431027)
73. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{v\to180}\frac{360\cos\left(\dfrac{v}{2}\right)}{180-v}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564021)
74. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{1-\cos(4x)}\right)^2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/409091)
75. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/891598)
76. [$\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0^+} (\cosh (3/y))^y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156866)
77. [$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{({\ln(1+x) -x +\frac{x^2}{2})^4}}{(\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2})^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/889879)
78. [$\displaystyle \displaystyle\lim_{z\to0} \operatorname{pv}\left(\cos(z)^\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/520824)
79. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}(\cos x)^{1/x^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/659428)
80. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \, \cos \left(\frac{\pi -\pi  \cos ^2(x)}{x^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/882149)
81. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos(3x)}{2x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832081)
82. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x \csc 10x}{\cos20x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/573832)
83. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(e^{2\tan(x)}-1) \cdot \ln(2-\cos^2(x))}{\sqrt{1+x^3}-(\cos x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576232)
84. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{(\cos{x}-1)(\cos{x}-e^{x})}{x^{n}} \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/336553)
85. [$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cosh(x))}{x\ln(1+x)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/585916)