# Should we have quick links? If yes, then how?

Tags: feature-request

These are very useful. Can we have quick links of them while answering or on sidebar of questions under some link?:
[Catalog of limits](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16717/catalog-of-limits), [a](https://mathindex.wordpress.com/), [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [List of comment templates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates), [List of Generalizations of Common Questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions)

Comment: Do you mean the comment "magic links" such as `[tour]` which takes you to [tour]?

Comment: @ArthurFischer probably under useful links besides help and review?Please.

Comment: Okay, I understand know. (Should have been obvious before but I was thinking of something else.) You want these pages to be easily accessible from every page on the site. I highly doubt that SE will mess with the top-bar in such a site-specific manner, but it's possible that a userscript could be made to serve this purpose. Also, certain users (read: those with diamonds) have pretty full top-bars as it stands, so adding more is likely a non-starter.

Comment: @ArthurFischer when the plate's full, we can get another plate(anoother bar) or look for another already present plate(already present empty location) or anywhere but we need it because it would be kinda useless to have such links without links.

Comment: I've made some pastelets for the comment templates, they will paste the respective template into the comment box (The text field must be opened by clicking on "comment" first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this will happen, but you could always use your browser's bookmark functionality for this. I've made some pastelets for the comments from comment templates and put them into a bookmark folder, for example.
All of these were made at [pastemark.ru](http://en.pastemark.ru/) using the target @comment. For some reason one of the comments doesn't work with this site however (I forgot which one).

Answer (score 3):

This might be potentially useful, but it's something users can handle themselves, i.e. using bookmarks or applets. It seems too small of a detail to be trying to make a network wide tweak.

Comment: The difference is that you have to know what the links are to bookmark them. If they were in a sidebar, people who didn't already know might find out.

Comment: @MJD The difference with respect to what?

Comment: The difference between OP's suggestion and your proposed alternative.

Comment: @MJD Yes. And users can try to be more meta active, too. If one surfs meta enough, one should bump into those very "big" threads.