# Can we include lists of common questions in the Helpful links tab when asking a question?

Tags: feature-request

I think various lists of common questions such as [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16717/888233) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1868/888233) should be added in the Helpful links tab as this may help lessen duplicate questions. Also, it will help expand the scope of questions being presented to the OP aside from the suggestions from the Similar questions.

Comment: I mean, when asking a new question, you see a Helpful links tab, maybe that can also help us find duplicates aside from the suggestions from the Similar questions.

Comment: I see, @soupless.  I didn't understand what you meant by "helpful links".  I think this could be very useful as well.